# PDFsharp and MigraDoc: How to render MigraDoc horizontal chart on PDFsharp page?

Tags: c#, pdf-generation, pdfsharp, migradoc

[image: PDF containing Horizontal chart in the cyan colored portion]

I have made a PDF document in MigraDoc containing all the details I need in my generated PDF file. The generated PDF page has two colored sections, cyan and white.
The cyan section contains horizontal charts.
I used another PDFsharp document and colored it in two parts, using the gfx of the PdfDocument page. Code below :

```
//---Color on page--------
gfx.DrawRectangle(new XSolidBrush(XColor.FromArgb(98, 183, 229)),    columnRect);
//---render migraddoc ---------------------------
MigraDoc.Rendering.DocumentRenderer docRenderer = new DocumentRenderer(document);
docRenderer.PrepareDocument();
//--- Render migradoc objects---------------------------------------------
docRenderer.RenderObject(gfx, XUnit.FromCentimeter(0.7), XUnit.FromCentimeter(0.5), "6cm", name);columnRect);
//-- above name is the migradoc paragraph object.
//-- ***rendering charts*** 
docRenderer.RenderObject(gfx, XUnit.FromCentimeter(1.2), XUnit.FromCentimeter(19), "0.6cm", chart);
```

***The rendered charts are getting overlapped one above the other***

```
 //--code for the chart
Chart chart = new Chart(ChartType.Bar2D);
chart.Width = Unit.FromPoint(100);
chart.Height = Unit.FromPoint(2);
chart.FillFormat.Color = Colors.White;

Series series = chart.SeriesCollection.AddSeries();

series.Add(new double[] {45, 20, 11, 23});
series.HasDataLabel = true;

XSeries xseries = chart.XValues.AddXSeries();
xseries.Add("A", "B", "C", "D");
document.LastSection.Add(chart);
```

Is there any way to render the series of the horizontal bars in proper format at the given coordinates?

Comment: Is there a reason for mixing PDFsharp and MigraDoc? You can use the Chart functions from PDFsharp (maybe those give you better control of position and size), you can use MigraDoc to create the entire PDF.

Comment: Hi, yes I needed this to color the page into two halves. One in cyan color while the other in white. Then  I had to fill the the data on this colored page. I could not achieve the coloring of the page in MigraDoc , as it required me to use table and then color rows. This was not feasible for my  requirement. I tried to put this horizontal chart but no success yet.